# Getting error "recursive indexing failed at level 2" in R when trying to recurse through list

Tags: r, visualization, igraph

I am getting an error "recursive indexing failed at level 2" when I try to recurse through a list of graph vertices, matching their value with a set of colors in a list.

My list of colors is as follows:

```
colrs <- list(l = "blue, c = "red", n = "gray50")
```

Then I have a list of vertices in an igraph `vs` object that have the values "l", "c", or "n" on a "value" attribute (i.e. V(g)$value).

The simple access that I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
colrs[[V(g)[1]$value]]
```

And the above works as I would like it to, returning the matching color. But when I try the following, I get the above mentioned error:

```
V(g)$color <- colrs[[V(g)$value]]
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to do is set a `color` attribute on each vertex based on the `value` attribute.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Would be greatly appreciated. I've not been able to find a good explanation anywhere else on the web.

Comment: Use this instead, 
    colrs[V(g)$value]

Double brackets can't be used to select multiple elements.